# Hyperlinks not showing up in Yahoo - PHP Mail Function

Tags: php, email, gmail, yahoo

I currently am running a site where students can buy and sell books to each other for my college. Its www.books4csusm.com. The past few days I have been getting e-mails where people are unable to delete their book.

After submitting their books they are sent an e-mail using PHP mail function and it displays their books along with a link to the right of the title to delete it.

It works for me on gmail(and it doesnt work for other people that use gmail, very weird) but I just tried it in yahoo and it looks like a link but you can't click it. At first I was using books4csusm@gmail.com to send the e-mail.

Then I did some research and found out that I should use an e-mail that corresponds to my domain so now I am using support@books4csusm.com

I am stuck and have no idea and I keep on getting e-mails from users asking if I can delete their book.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amm0p.png

It is showing up as a link but when you click it nothing happens. When I inspect element this is what it shows.

```
 <a id="yui_3_7_2_1_1377788967568_2506" rel="nofollow">
  Delete Book
</a>
```

No idea what to do

```
function send_book_email($email, $post_id, $name)
{
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "$name , Your Book(s) have been Submitted!";
    $message = "Hello $name,<br><br>Thank you for using www.books4csusm.com. <strong>Please do not delete this e-mail.</strong><br><br>";
    $message .= "<strong>Title</strong><br>";

    $book_id = get_book_id($post_id);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($book_id))
        {
            $message .=  "" . $row['title'] . " - <a href='www.books4csusm.com/remove_new.php?PostID=" . $post_id . "&BookID=" . $row['bookID'] . "'>Delete Book</a><br>";
        }
        $message .= "<br><br>To delete your book Select the Delete book above of the corresponding book.<br>";
        $message .= "<br><br>Don't forget to like us on Facebook <a href='https://www.facebook.com/Books4Csusm'>https://www.facebook.com/Books4Csusm</a><br><br>BOOKS4CSUSM";

       $from = "support@books4csusm.com";
       $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= "From:" . $from;
       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
```

Comment: If you're getting inconsistent results like that, I'd imagine that your emails are triggering Yahoo's spam filter, and the hyperlinks are being disabled to protect the users. You'll need to try and make your emails look less like spam, which isn't easy to do - I think setting up SPF Records would help.

Comment: I am trying to find out how to set up SPF records. Is it through my webmail with my hosting website?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not something I know enough about to be able to help. An SPF record is essentially a way of telling mail servers that a given mail server has your permission to send emails that are marked as coming from your domain; you're going to have to speak to the people who are hosting your website and get them to do something, I believe.

Comment: There's some good information on ServerFault.com - http://serverfault.com/questions/369460/what-are-spf-records-and-how-do-i-configure-them

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I figured it out though and it was so simple that I overlooked it. I added the http:// to the www.books4csusm.com/remove_new and now it works. It does not show up as spam in yahoo and I can now delete it. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out though and it was so simple that I overlooked it. I added the

```
 http:// to the www.books4csusm.com/remove_new
```

and now it works. It does not show up as spam in yahoo and I can now delete the books that i have poseted.

Comment: in my case i have already attached http:// with the link but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `http://` before adding your domain to the variable or link.

No spam is reason or not needed any settings.

**Just Put http:// in your url and you are done**

```
$url="www.example.com"; // Is Wrong in php mailer for yahoo

$url="http://example.com/"; // it will work in yahoo.in gmail.
```

But you should test it with Outlook also.